# Linker error while building clang using Makefile with a checker

Tags: macos, c++11, linker, clang, llvm

I'm facing a problem during the linking phase.

What am I trying to do?

I'm trying to add a checker to clang. I built LLVM and libc++ from the source code (Yes, some test failed during libcxx testing after build). To identify the libc++ library, I added the following code to the Clang's root directory Makefile

```
CXX.Flags += -stdlib=libc++
CXX.Flags += -std=c++11
CXX.Flags += -nostdinc++
CXX.Flags += -I/path/to/my/own/c++library/libcxx/include
LD.Flags += -L/path/to/my/own/c++library/libcxx/lib
```

The linker problem surfaced as following.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"std::__1::__shared_weak_count::__get_deleter(std::type_info const&) const", referenced from:
      vtable for std::__1::__shared_ptr_p-traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<<<std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<<<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
      std::__1::regex_traits<char>::__init() in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<<<std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<<<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
  "std::__1::__get_classname(char const*, bool)", referenced from:
      unsigned int std::__1::regex_traits<char>::__lookup_classname<char const*>(char const*, char const*, bool, char) const in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
  "std::__1::__shared_weak_count::__add_shared()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> >::basic_regex(std::__1::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> > const&) in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
  "std::__1::__shared_weak_count::__release_shared()", referenced from:
      std::__1::shared_ptr<std::__1::__empty_state<char> >::~shared_ptr() in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
  "std::__1::__shared_weak_count::~__shared_weak_count()", referenced from:
      std::__1::__shared_ptr_pointer<std::__1::__empty_state<char>*, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__empty_state<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__empty_state<char> > >::~__shared_ptr_pointer() in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
  "std::__1::__get_collation_name(char const*)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::regex_traits<char>::__lookup_collatename<char const*>(char const*, char const*, char) const in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::regex_traits<char>::__lookup_collatename<char*>(char*, char*, char) const in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
  "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
      (anonymous namespace)::ObjCSelfInitChecker::checkPreStmt(clang::ObjCStringLiteral const*, clang::ento::CheckerContext&) const in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<<<std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<<<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
      std::__1::regex_traits<char>::__init() in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
  "std::__1::locale::locale(std::__1::locale const&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> >::__start_matching_list(bool) in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
      std::__1::regex_traits<char>::regex_traits(std::__1::regex_traits<char> const&) in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
  "std::__1::locale::locale()", referenced from:
      std::__1::regex_traits<char>::regex_traits() in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<<<std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
      std::__1::regex_traits<char>::~regex_traits() in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<<<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
      std::__1::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> >::__start_matching_list(bool) in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
  "std::__1::collate<char>::id", referenced from:
      std::__1::regex_traits<char>::__init() in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
  "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<<<std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::put(char) in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::flush() in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry() in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<<<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
  "vtable for std::__1::__shared_count", referenced from:
      std::__1::shared_ptr<std::__1::__empty_state<char> >::shared_ptr<std::__1::__empty_state<char>, void>(std::__1::__empty_state<char>*) in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for std::__1::__shared_weak_count", referenced from:
      std::__1::shared_ptr<std::__1::__empty_state<char> >::shared_ptr<std::__1::__empty_state<char>, void>(std::__1::__empty_state<char>*) in libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a(ObjCSelfInitChecker.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [/Users/msecurity/Documents/Deepak/Eclipse/clang_build/build/Debug+Asserts/bin/clang] Error 1
make[1]: *** [driver/.makeall] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I followed the linker's suggestion to use -v option to see linker invocation, and got the following output.

```
"/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.8.0 -o /path/to/onw/clang/build/Debug+Asserts/bin/clang -L/path/to/onw/clang//build/Debug+Asserts/lib -L/path/to/onw/clang/build/Debug+Asserts/lib -L/path/to/libc++/build/libcxx/lib -rpath @executable_path/../lib -sectcreate __TEXT __info_plist /path/to/onw/clang/build/tools/clang/tools/driver/Debug+Asserts/Info.plist /path/to/onw/clang/build/tools/clang/tools/driver/Debug+Asserts/cc1_main.o /path/to/onw/clang/build/tools/clang/tools/driver/Debug+Asserts/cc1as_main.o /path/to/onw/clang/build/tools/clang/tools/driver/Debug+Asserts/driver.o -lclangFrontendTool -lclangFrontend -lclangDriver -lclangSerialization -lclangCodeGen -lclangParse -lclangSema -lclangStaticAnalyzerFrontend -lclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers -lclangStaticAnalyzerCore -lclangARCMigrate -lclangRewriteFrontend -lclangRewriteCore -lclangAnalysis -lclangEdit -lclangAST -lclangBasic -lclangLex -lLLVMOption -lLLVMLinker -lLLVMIRReader -lLLVMipo -lLLVMVectorize -lLLVMInstrumentation -lLLVMBitWriter -lLLVMBitReader -lLLVMAsmParser -lLLVMR600CodeGen -lLLVMR600Desc -lLLVMR600Info -lLLVMR600AsmPrinter -lLLVMSystemZDisassembler -lLLVMSystemZCodeGen -lLLVMSystemZAsmParser -lLLVMSystemZDesc -lLLVMSystemZInfo -lLLVMSystemZAsmPrinter -lLLVMHexagonCodeGen -lLLVMHexagonAsmPrinter -lLLVMHexagonDesc -lLLVMHexagonInfo -lLLVMNVPTXCodeGen -lLLVMNVPTXDesc -lLLVMNVPTXInfo -lLLVMNVPTXAsmPrinter -lLLVMCppBackendCodeGen -lLLVMCppBackendInfo -lLLVMMSP430CodeGen -lLLVMMSP430Desc -lLLVMMSP430Info -lLLVMMSP430AsmPrinter -lLLVMXCoreDisassembler -lLLVMXCoreCodeGen -lLLVMXCoreDesc -lLLVMXCoreInfo -lLLVMXCoreAsmPrinter -lLLVMMipsDisassembler -lLLVMMipsCodeGen -lLLVMMipsAsmParser -lLLVMMipsDesc -lLLVMMipsInfo -lLLVMMipsAsmPrinter -lLLVMARMDisassembler -lLLVMARMCodeGen -lLLVMARMAsmParser -lLLVMARMDesc -lLLVMARMInfo -lLLVMARMAsmPrinter -lLLVMAArch64Disassembler -lLLVMAArch64CodeGen -lLLVMAArch64AsmParser -lLLVMAArch64Desc -lLLVMAArch64Info -lLLVMAArch64AsmPrinter -lLLVMAArch64Utils -lLLVMPowerPCCodeGen -lLLVMPowerPCAsmParser -lLLVMPowerPCDesc -lLLVMPowerPCInfo -lLLVMPowerPCAsmPrinter -lLLVMSparcCodeGen -lLLVMSparcDesc -lLLVMSparcInfo -lLLVMX86Disassembler -lLLVMX86AsmParser -lLLVMX86CodeGen -lLLVMSelectionDAG -lLLVMAsmPrinter -lLLVMMCParser -lLLVMCodeGen -lLLVMObjCARCOpts -lLLVMScalarOpts -lLLVMInstCombine -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMipa -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMX86Desc -lLLVMX86Info -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMX86AsmPrinter -lLLVMMC -lLLVMObject -lLLVMX86Utils -lLLVMCore -lLLVMSupport -lz -lpthread -lcurses -lm -lstdc++ -lSystem /usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.2/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

I observed that it's using the C++11 library that I built for it, as it is the 6th option to ld in above invocation. Is there any other options that I should take care of ?

I tried to google out if any solution is available, and I found this kind of problem of missing vtable entries for non-inline virtual function existed in the earlier versions of llvm, and using the latest version helped others. But I'm already using llvm latest version. The following is the clang -v output

```
clang version 3.4 (trunk 192102) (llvm/trunk 192100)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Please guide me with the possible way to solve the problem. Let me know if I need to share any more details. If I'm any way, violating any conventions or norms(this is my first question on StackOverflow), I'm sorry for that, and kindly let me know.

***Please Note: I added a checker earlier and it was working fine and fulfilled my purpose. All the above problem raised when I tried to include standard C++ header <regex> to extend the same checker.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the linker cmdline, you're trying to link using libstdc++ (-lstdc++). So, you're mixing the objects compiled with libc++ with libstdc++

Comment: Correct my understanding, if it's wrong. Compiling LLVM with C++11 standard and letting the linker know to use libc++ library should overcome my problem. To do so I configured LLVM using following command `../llvm/configure CXXFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11" OBJCXXFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11" LDFLAGS=-"stdlib=libc++"` and Make it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved. Compiling LLVM with following configuration options helped me to resolve the issue.

`../llvm/configure \
CXXFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11" \
OBJCXXFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11" \
LDFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++"`

May be it will help someone someday. Thank you all.

Comment: AND IT DID HELP! Have been fighting a similar error for a day now, until your post made me add "-stdlib=libc++" as a linker flag, Now thing work! Thank you!